# How to place an IF statement in a title attribute on a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, customlabel, rendered, if

I have a syntax issue with this line of code:

```
<apex:sectionHeader title="{!if(!PP_IsOwner,!$Label.D1,!$Label.D2)} />
```

Here is the relevant line of code from the controller:

```
public Boolean PP_Detect {get; set;}
```

it returns this error:

```
Incorrect parameter type for function 'not()'. Expected Boolean, received Text
```

PP_isOwner is a boolean field, if its value is set to true then I want to display the D1 label, else D2 label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulas in Visualforce start with `{!`, and end with `}`. Individual fields do not start with `!`; using `!` inside the formula works as the not operator.

```
{!if(PP_IsOwner, $Label.D1, $Label.D2)}
```

Comment: I see what you mean and it does work however I do have other lines of code (without the if statement) where I reference a label with the !$ notation such as: <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!$Label.Escalation}" columns="1"> and it works, how do you explain this?

Comment: @Dante The merge field itself starts with `{!`. So, the formula is actually `$Label.Escalation`. Do not consider the opening `{!` and `}` as part of the actual formula, it simply tells Visualforce that there's an expression to evaluate.

Comment: @Dante You're welcome! Glad I could help!